# PHP Shell EXEC with Plesk

Tags: php, plesk, shell-exec

1. I made a SH script to add Plesk subscription (newplesk.sh)
2. I need this script to be started from a PHP file.
3. It's working through SSH when typing `php testplesk.php`
4. It's not working when I enter the direct path into web browser (https://example.com/testplesk.php)

testplesk.php :

```
<?php
/// testplesk.php
exec('php testshell.php');
?>
```

testshell.php :

```
<?php
/// testshell.php
shell_exec('sudo sh newplesk.sh');
?>
```

newplesk.sh :

```
plesk bin subscription --create 6.domain.tld -owner admin -service-plan "Default Domain" -ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -login jdoe6 -passwd "pwd6"
```

All of these files are chown in xxx:psacln

Any help please ?
Best Regards.

---

EDIT (Reason : Answer)

The web user had to be in sudoers and the path to plesk in absolute path

`nano /etc/sudoers`

Last line of "sudoers" :

`yourwebuser ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/plesk`

newplesk.sh (modified & with var) :

`sudo /usr/sbin/plesk bin customer --create $1 -name $2 -passwd sample -phone $4 -company $5 -email $6 -notify false`

*Thanks to Luka who helped me for that*

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'not working'. Share any errors you may see. Are you sure PHP running from your webserver has access to `sudo` and `sh`?

Comment: Running `sudo` from a web-server is plain stupid (unless adding `apache` into group `wheel` and passing the password, this won't even work); just use crontab, let it pick up jobs. That PHP install might have `exec()` & `shell_exec()` disabled (think it's even the default value).

Comment: file has work permission? if not exists permisson 
you can add permission 
```chmod +x ./yourfile.sh```
and again try out

Comment: Script is working when launched through SSH, .SH is chmod +x and probably PHP is sudoer since it's working in SSH when typing ```php testplesk.php```

The subscription is added this way in Plesk but it has to be from a custom PHP file without any SSH connection.

Regards

EDIT : i change the path to absolute but don't know where is plesk location

Answer (score 1):

Actually your method is unsecure. I think you can do your process with Plesk API.

For example:

curl -i -X GET -u admin:***** "https://yourserver-address:8443/api/v2/server"

You can run this command with PHP curl or guzzle.

This method is safer and more convenient than the previous one.